# robotframework/rfdocker says it is python3 and debian buster based but cannot use apt-get in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, robotframework, debian-based, debian-buster

As the title says when I try to run an 'apt-get -y update' command when building my Robotframework Dockerfile I get the error below:

*/bin/sh: apt-get: not found*

*executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update]: exit code: 127*

Can anyone help in explaining why this is the case as per my understanding this should run due to the Debian Buster base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docker layers on the docker-hub site, it seems, that they decided to use `Alpine Linux` instead of `Debian`.
While adding new packages they used `apk` instead of `apt-get`, as can be seen [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/rfdocker/robotframework/rfdocker/latest/images/sha256-70636fdd3277ba1145f2e9c60e0d189b6cd5cebb594ddc78006513e9b7ad418f?context=explore).

So you may want to use `apk update` instead of `apt-get update`

Comment: Thank you, that appears to have sorted this issue